# How to insert records into table in loop?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, loops

I have a table with non-autoincrement ID field. I need to create an varchar array and then insert data from array into table.

The problem is that I don't know how to declare such array. And also I don't know how to address the value by the index in the loop.

```
declare @newCodesList - ???
declare @counter int = 0
declare @lastID int = (select MAX(Id) from OrganizationCode)

while @counter < LEN(@newCodesList)
begin
    @lastID = @lastID + 1

    insert into OrganizationCodeCopy values(@lastID, @newCodesList[@counter])

    @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

In code upper I try to insert values in the loop after finding last record ID and declaring counter

Comment: in the code above I dont see any need for an array. Why do you need it ? It would help if you explained what you are trying to achieve, maybe there are better methods to do it

Comment: Why use a loop? Use a set based method. What are you actually tried to achieve here?

Comment: I need a script, which updates the table, filling it with new values.I have never tried to insert many NEW values, so the loop is the first thing, came in my head) The main idea that only new data was typed manually. I mean that last time I inserted 20 values by my hands. @GuidoG

Comment: Looks like a job for `STRING_SPLIT` and/or a join on a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506/97345) (or a straight join on `@newCodesList` if it's actually a table-valued parameter). You don't want to write loops in SQL if you can possibly avoid it; find a way to recast your problem in terms of tables instead.

Comment: For a more general discussion on how to handle arrays of values in SQL, see [this](http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) and [this](http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a table variable to store the codes in. Then do an `INSERT ... SELECT` from that variable. To get the IDs you can use `row_number()` the your maximum ID from the other table.

```
DECLARE @codes TABLE
               (code nvarchar(4));

INSERT INTO @codes
            (code)
            VALUES ('A01B'),
                   ('B03C'),
                   ('X97K');

INSERT INTO organizationcodecopy
            (id,
             code)
            SELECT (SELECT coalesce(max(id), 0)
                           FROM organizationcode) + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY code) id,
                   code
                   FROM @codes;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=455e8df61c46f6f21192a977b8f21046)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array, you can use a comma separated string. Like following:

```
DECLARE @newCodesList VARCHAR(MAX) = 'value1,value2'
DECLARE @lastID int = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM OrganizationCode)

INSERT INTO OrganizationCodeCopy 
(
    Id, 
    Code
)
SELECT 
    @lastID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id
    Element AS Code
FROM 
    asi_SplitString(@newCodesList, ',')
```

Comment: Where does `asi_SplitString` come from?

Comment: @ThomasSchremser Sorry I forgot to mention that the function is not available in all iterations of SQL server. However, you can find the function script here: http://docs.imis.com/15.2/Schema/Programmability/Functions/Table-valued_Functions/asi_SplitString.html

Answer (score 1):

Using loops is not a good solution. You may try to define a temporary table and insert new data with one statement. Values for `Id` are generated with `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
-- New data
CREATE TABLE #NewCodes (
    Code varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #NewCodes
    (Code)
VALUES
    ('Code1'),
    ('Code2'),
    ('Code3'),
    ('Code4'),
    ('Code5'),
    ('Code6')

-- Last ID
DECLARE @LastID int
SELECT @LastId = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Id), 0) FROM OrganizationCode)

-- Statement
INSERT INTO OrganizationCode
    (Id, Code)
SELECT
    @LastId + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code) AS Id,
    [Code]
FROM #NewCodes
```